# State of the art motion blur recovery

Tags: motion

Could the experts point me towards the best motion de blur algorithm? My images are blurred where I know the motion information with good precision(direction and angle)

There are so many deconvolution algorithms however I was not able to figure out which one would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really hard to say which one is the best unless we define more precisely what we mean by "best." Some algorithms measure performance using MSE, others use more fancy metrics like entropy.

Since you know the angle and direction of blur, it seems you have a good idea about the blurring function (point spread function). I would start off with a minimum mean squared error type filter (Wiener filter).

Answer (score 0):

It is a good step to start with the PSF, and use it in the form of a deconvolving function. I think, last year Adobe showed the results of their algorithm to remove the motion blur. They had blurred the test image using a known blurring function, and removed the blur blindly, and I think it is now included in Photoshop. Since you already know the blurring kernel, any error minimization based deconvolution will be a good starting point. You can refer to the Image Reconstruction section in [this paper](http://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/deblur_fergus.pdf).